# Raspberry Pi mount Samba Network Share

Tags: mount, samba, raspberry-pi, fstab, arm

I tried for at least 3 hours to mount my Network Share to my Pi... I searched on many posts and tried so many things. But nothing worked...

I want to mount my Share over the `/etc/fstab` file so I edited the file with `sudo nano /etc/fstab` and added the last line of code:

```
//HOGWARTS-WIFI/Elements /mnt/share cifs username=msusername,password=mspassword,uid=1000,gid=1000,iocharset=utf8 0 0
```

When I checked with `sudo mount -av` this error appears:

```
mount.cifs kernel mount options: ip=192.168.2.1,unc=\\HOGWARTS-WIFI\Elements,iocharset=utf8,uid=1000,gid=1000,user=msusername,pass=********
mount error(13): Permission denied
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs)
```

What do I need to do?

Answer (score 0):

Whenever I run into issues mounting CIFS shares I generally turn debugging on.

See:
https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/LinuxCIFS_troubleshooting

One thing I ran into recently is that actual Windows CIFS shares usually do not require the domain name. However, on a samba file share I have that authenticates (using kerberos) against a domain control you must include the domain portion. As an example here is what I have in my fstab (with comments):

Share served by Windows Server 2008:

//appdeploy/c$ /mnt/appdeploy_admin cifs noauto,username=my.username,uid=user,gid=user     0 0

Share served by Samba using kerberos authentication:

//storage/TSC /mnt/TSC-STORAGE  cifs  noauto,username=my.username,domain=local,uid=user,gid=user